# ISAPI Rewrite - HTTP to HTTPS redirect for a particular web page

Tags: asp.net, iis, isapi-rewrite

I have this `ISAPI Rewrite` rule that is working:

```
RewriteRule ^/signup$ /signup.aspx [I,L]
```

and I want to redirect the traffic to `HTTPS` for this web page.

I tried this rule and other similar rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule  ^/signup$ https://www.domain.com/signup.aspx [I,L]
```

and I receive `404 error` message.

I also tried to keep the first rule and create a new one to redirect `http://www.domain.com/signup` to `https://www.domain.com/signup` but the traffic remains on HTTP.

Comment: If it's ISAPI_Rewrite 2 that you are using, you might want to try the following syntax:

RewriteCond %HTTPS (?!(.*on.*)).*
RewriteRule  /signup https://www.domain.com/signup.aspx [I,L]

Comment: I'm using IsapiRewrite4.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. The same 404 error.

Comment: Before you go rewriting the URL, verify you can even access the page via HTTPS. Once you know it will be successful, *then* write your rule.

Comment: Both `https://www.domain.com/signup` and `https://www.domain.com/signup.aspx` works fine.

Comment: I would suggest as an aside just turn HTTPS on for everything.

Comment: I don't want to put the whole website under HTTPS.